# Listing all terms of a taxonomy in twig template

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

How can I list all terms of a particular taxonomy in a twig template?

Answer (score 4):

Build a view for the list of taxonomy terms and use the module [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
<dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}</dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using an unlimited cardinality taxonomy reference field (in field_topic) which creates links to a Search-API view page and pre-selects the 'Topic' facet value with the proper term id:

```
{% for term in node.field_topic %}
    {% set link = "/search?f[0]=topic%3A" ~ term.entity.id %}
    {% set label = term.entity.label %}
    <a href="{{ link }}" class="button-link">{{ label }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```